# Is it possible to add a single item to a vis.js timeline?

Tags: javascript, timeline, vis.js

I'd like to add a single item to a vis.js timeline, but this doesn't seem to be possible. The closest I can get is `setItems`, which replaces everything in the timeline with the new items. Is there a way to non-destructively add a new item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After tracing through the code, I discovered that the following works:

```
var item = {
  id: 34654,
  type: 'background',
  start: new Date(2015, 04, 01, 02, 01, 29),
  end: new Date(2015, 04, 13, 06, 23, 22),
  content: 'New Item',
  title: 'New Item'
};

timeline.itemsData.getDataSet().add(item);
```

If you want to change an item, simply call

```
timeline.itemsData.getDataSet().remove(item);
```

before the add call - it will locate the existing item by its id.

Answer (score 1):

For me this worked:

```
timeline.itemsData.add(myItem);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Even without "citations" this is the actual right answer.